# If a user doesn't quote references properly, then will Mods delete majority of their answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, moderators, flagging, post-quality

There is a user, who is consistently **not** quoting the references in their answers. Wherever there is a mention of the reference, it's not in form of quote but it's just a last line. (e.g. "Ref: Manusmruti, Srimad Bhagavatam").
Rarely their answers are quoted with source and is long enough not to be a comment.

I had an impression that we have pretty strict standards for quality from my personal experience in past.
What stops the Mods to delete this user's answer?

---

I assume that Mods may know about this user.
Yet they can see my last flag in the main site and they will already know.
<sub><sup>As of today, this Avatar of Vishnu is reputed enough to see deleted answers of others.</sup></sub>

Comment: If we are thinking of the same user, I think some of them were deleted. I know of one of their answers is deleted already. That didn't come into attention of many.

Comment: 'What stops the Mods to delete this user's answer?' Pick from 1)  'We are busy',  2) 'It missed our radar; we are also human' 3) 'We were waiting for someone to flag' 4) 'User is senior member, ans. is correct (agrees with our/majority view anyway) but just missing sources. You should try to improve the answer instead of flagging and wasting our time' 5) 'Meta is the not correct place to discuss such things, use the chat room instead'

Comment: Yes. Their majority of answers should be deleted as per rules and will do so after finally notifying them. Use flags to bring that to Mod(s) attention.

Comment: "As of today, this Avatar of Vishnu is reputed enough to see deleted answers of others." Is this a hint for finding out who that user is? BTW how many points does one need to be able to view others' deleted answers? @@Milind

Comment: Yes @Rickross, you may refer [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/163449) to see various reputation privilges. It's different for graduated and beta sites.

Comment: Okay it's over 2000 for Beta sites. @I